# Getting rid power to a fraction, decimal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

this should be a relatively simple mathematics question but just can't seem to locate the solution anywhere to these sort of problems and would appreciate any recommendation!

$K^ {0.75} =
 \bigg(\dfrac{xQ^{0.3}} {Z}\bigg)$

Should $0.75$ be adjusted to become a fraction, $\frac{3}{4}$ so that the equation would be more straightforward?

Am looking at isolating K, so K expressed as a function of all the other variables but am not sure how to get rid of the power to $0.75$, thanks!

Comment: Raise both expressions to the $\dfrac43$th power.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Although it would look nicer, it is not necessary to express $0.75$ as a fraction to solve this problem.

To cancel the power of $0.75$, raise both sides of the equation to the power of $1/0.75$. By the [exponents rule](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/algebra/how-to-raise-powers-of-powers/) $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$, the power of $K$ will become $0.75\cdot\frac{1}{0.75}=1$.

\begin{align*}
K^ {0.75} &= \frac{xQ^{0.3}}  {Z} \\
(K^{0.75})^{1/0.75}&= \left( \frac{xQ^{0.3}}{Z} \right)^{1/0.75} \\
K&=\left( \frac{xQ^{0.3}}{Z} \right)^{1/0.75} \\
K&=\left( \frac{xQ^{0.3}}{Z} \right)^{4/3} 
\end{align*}
Of course you could have written $0.75$ as $\frac34$ and $\frac{1}{0.75}$ as $\frac43$ and done the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

A different view of the "power" makes the solution easier to see.

\begin{align*}
K^ {0.75}= K^ {\frac{3}{4}} =\sqrt[\Large{4}]{k^3}
 = \bigg(\frac{xQ^{0.3}}{Z}\bigg)\\ \\
\implies
 =K^3 = \bigg(\frac{xQ^{0.3}}{Z}\bigg)^{\large{4}}\\ \\
\implies
 =K = \sqrt[\huge{3}]
{\bigg(\frac{xQ^{0.3}}{Z}\bigg)^{\large{4}}}
\end{align*}